# How to apply flex in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-widget

I am a beginner in a flutter, and I have learned how to handle the sizing and text rendering when the screen sizing changes from desktop to tablet to mobile. But I want to understand how can I change the sizing or flex the content when I am decreasing the screen size within the same screen mode.

For Instance -

```
return Container(
  child: new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[new Text("Hello World")],
      ),
      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
              "This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is ")
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

With this scenario when I try to decrease the screen size from desktop to table I start getting oveflow exception. Please guide me on how to handle it.

Comment: you can wrap your widget with `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget, and use flex property inside  `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget

Answer (score 33):

Expanded is Similar to Flex and supports adding flex,

You can wrap your children with Expanded and give flex as below

Updated Code :

```
Container(
  child: new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Expanded ( 
        flex:1,
        child : Column(
        children: <Widget>[new Text("Hello World")],
      ),),
      new Expanded( 
        flex :2,
        child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
              "This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is ")
        ],
      ),)
    ],
  ),
)
```

Expanded : A widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the child fills the available space.

You can read more at official docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

Answer (score 10):

Widgets inside a `Flex` widget (eg. `Column, Row`) can be wrapped in the Flexible widget. The `Flexible` widget has flex propery. Flutter has 3 flexible widgets: [Flexible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI7x0mAZiY0), [Expanded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo) and [Spacer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FJgd7QN1zI)

```
return Container(
child: new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      flex: 1 /*or any integer value above 0 (optional)*/,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              flex: 1 /*or any integer value above 0 (optional)*/,
              child: new Text("Hello World")),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(
            "This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is This is a long text this is a long test this is ")
      ],
    )
  ],
),

);
```